# MVC Razor GUI and Coder Working Together

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, user-interface, razor, editor, wysiwyg

I would really like to use the MVC and Razor technology for my web application. The problem I am running into is that I am the coder and will be working with a HTML GUI designer.

I only see 2 ways for the GUI person to work at this point.

1. Install Visual Studio and open the whole solution and work like I am working, except he would stick to the CSHTML files.
2. Use his favorite HTML editor or notepad and edit the CSHTML files manually and then also have something like IIS Express installed with the app configured so that they can refresh the page they are working on.

Neither of these seems productive or intuitive. I would love to see the GUI person able to use a tool like Expression Web or other tools that allow you to see the design and html at the same time. Having tools available for shading and colors and positioning would be good.

Now I understand why it is this way. It is because of the processing that Razor does to render the pages. This is most true by the fact that most of the cshtml pages themselves are not complete pages. They are meant to live inside of a _layout page.

Isn't there something, though, that can at least show the basic rendering during editor?

What are other people doing?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.  AFAIK there is no WYSIWYG HTML editor that understands Razor.  So, either your designer must work in straight html, or...

1) The designer works in pure HTML files.  They give you those files, and you adapt them to Razor.  If they need to make changes, you can track those changes with a diff tool (from the previous version) or use a version control system to compare versions of the raw html.  Then you apply those changes to your Razor files.

2) Your designer works in .aspx files, which Expression Web understands.  You could convert the WebForm syntax to Razor syntax.  Again, you are spent doing  lot of work, but probably less work than the pure HTML way of doing things, because the designer will have designed the code for master pages.  These can be relatively easily adapted to Layouts.

It would be nice if the next version of Expression understands Razor.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not marking this as answered yet just because I hope maybe someone else has other options as well.